# How to set two autocmd BufWritePre in .vimrc

Tags: vim, vi, autocmd

On save/write in VIM I want to trim trailing whitespace and ensure that the file's line endings are UNIX and not DOS.

Both of these commands work on their own, but I can't figure out how to get them to BOTH run on write/save of a file in VIM.

```
autocmd BufWritePre,FileWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e
autocmd BufWritePre,FileWritePre * :%s/\r$//
```

I've tried all of the following and still VIM throws errors:

```
autocmd BufWritePre,FileWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e|:%s/\r$//
```

OR

```
autocmd BufWritePre,FileWritePre * %s/\s\+$//e|%s/\r$//
```

AND

```
augroup prewrites
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePre,FileWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e
    autocmd BufWritePre,FileWritePre * :%s/\r$//                                                                                             
augroup END
```

None of these produce the desired result without errors being thrown by VI. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The culprit was not ending the second search with an `e` after. See end result below:

```
augroup prewrites
   autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePre,FileWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e | %s/\r$//e
augroup END
```